# Search Result shows from sites where user does not have permission

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

**What I have?**

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application with FBA configured and it is exposed to Internet. The root site collection has a huge hierarchy and each site has document libraries with many documents.

There are more than 10 site groups defined and some of them has access only to some sites.

**What problem am I facing?**

Everything was working fine and suddenly I am facing a problem in Enterprise Search.

When a user searches, the search result displays everything (including the site where user does not have permission) and clicking on a result it either opens the item (page/document) or shows **Access denied** error depending on whether the user has permission on that item.

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally figured out the problem with this one.

We had given `Full Read` permissions to `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` for `All zones` in User Policy of the web applications in question. I am not sure of the reason for giving this permission. We removed it. Then, a full crawl fixed the issue.

Thanks!